# Problem with awk and (maybe) null characters

Tags: awk, binary, mawk

I have this file, which "may be" a binary file:

```
    DATA FIELDINFO Cloud_Mask_QA {{{
  rank: 2
  type: 20
  dims: Cell_Along_Swath_1km 2030, Cell_Across_Swath_1km 1354, 
  data: ... (2748620)
    (0,0) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,16) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,32) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,48) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,64) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,80) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,96) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,112) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,128) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,144) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,160) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,176) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
    (0,192) ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@, ^@
```

If I use `sed -n "l" file`, in order to see the "non printable characters" I get:

```
    DATA FIELDINFO Cloud_Mask_QA {{{$
  rank: 2$
  type: 20$
  dims: Cell_Along_Swath_1km 2030, Cell_Across_Swath_1km 1354, $
  data: ... (2748620)$
    (0,0) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \
   \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,16) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \
   \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,32) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \
   \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,48) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \
    \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,64) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \
    \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,80) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \
    \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,96) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \
    \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,112) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000,\
    \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,128) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000,\
    \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,144) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000,\
    \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,160) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000,\
    \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,176) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000,\
    \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
    (0,192) \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000,\
    \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000, \000$
```

I am trying to use awk on it, but if I do `awk '{print $0}' file`, I get:

```
    DATA FIELDINFO Cloud_Mask_QA {{{
  rank: 2
  type: 20
  dims: Cell_Along_Swath_1km 2030, Cell_Across_Swath_1km 1354, 
  data: ... (2748620)
    (0,0)
```

So it seems that awk stops processing the file at the first "^@" or "\000" character it founds.

How can I avoid this?

Note: it seems my `awk` is `mawk`

Comment: `s/may be/is/`. Per POSIX a text file cannot contain NUL characters. Having said that, GNU awk can handle NULs in input files so make sure you're running GNU awk (`awk --version`) and then let us know if you still have a problem.

Comment: can you upload the file and give a link to it

Comment: Ok, I just tried in another computer with GNU awk `gawk`. It works! However, I am not "root" user in the computer with `mawk`, so I would still like to have a `mawk` solution... if not possible, I'll try to locally install `awk` type `gawk`

Comment: It definetively works with `gawk`

Answer (score 0):

`gawk` seems to solve the problem, instead of `mawk`. `awk` is generally linked to one of those two, so the only thing to do is to install `gawk` and use it instead of `awk`.